# android eclipse debug jar file with source code

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, jar

I am trying to debug a jar file with attached source code. I am able to debug it step by step, but unable to see any variable values.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to see variable values in Java bytecode, it needs to be compiled with debug symbols.  A typical release version of a jar will not have this debug info.

Related: [Why are some java libraries compiled without debugging information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872491/why-are-some-java-libraries-compiled-without-debugging-information)

Typically, in this case I make a debug variable in my own code before the breakpoint, something like:

```
...
int debugVal = libraryClass.getValueIWantToDebug();
System.out.println("Breakpoint");
...
```

Then you'll have the value in your own code, which will be accessible during debug.